# flowfram staticframe not reaching full page height

Tags: geometry, flowfram

I'm setting up a layout for a A3-sized poster with a few static frames. For some reason I can't seem to have the top line up with the page, and I don't know where the problem might be.

I'm also curious to know if there's a way to have only flowframe elements in the document (I've had to insert a dummy `~` for it to compile).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=297mm, paperheight=420mm,margin=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[width=35truecm,height=45truecm,cam,noinfo,center]{crop}

\usepackage[draft]{flowfram}
\setallstaticframes{valign=t}
\newstaticframe[1]{297mm}{110mm}
                   {0mm}{310mm}[titlearea]
\newstaticframe[1]{297mm}{420mm}
                   {0mm}{0mm}[page]

\begin{document}
\showframebboxtrue

~ % dummy content

\begin{staticcontents*}{titlearea}
\begin{center} \large\textsc{titlearea} \end{center} 
\end{staticcontents*}

\begin{staticcontents*}{page}
\begin{center} \large\textsc{page} \end{center} 
\end{staticcontents*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you put `\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}` into the document, it will not be aligned with the crop marks either.  Removing the flowfam package fixes it.  Removing crop does not.

Comment: yep, I did check that crop wasn't interfering

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but this seems to work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=297mm, paperheight=420mm,margin=0mm,noheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage[width=35truecm,height=45truecm,cam,noinfo,center]{crop}

\usepackage{flowfram}
\setallstaticframes{valign=t}
\newstaticframe[1]{297mm}{110mm}
                   {0mm}{310mm}[titlearea]
\newstaticframe[1]{297mm}{420mm}
                   {0mm}{0mm}[page]
\newflowframe[1]{\textwidth}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\newflowframe[>1]{\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{staticcontents*}{titlearea}
\begin{center} \large\textsc{titlearea} \end{center} 
\end{staticcontents*}

\begin{staticcontents*}{page}
\begin{center} \large\textsc{page} \end{center} 
\end{staticcontents*}

\begin{document}
\showframebboxtrue
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice, thanks! I suspect it's what the warning was about `Package flowfram Warning: Run out of flows frames on page 1, adding new one on input line 75.`. Adding one explicitly of the full page size seems to fix it. (or 2 rather, for some reason)